# Partial unpersist of spark dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am performing a join by bucketizing one of my dataframes and, given the frequent use of the dataframes I have persisted them to cache. However I see that the total time spent in GC has increased to >10% of execution time.

Is it possible for me to perform in scala a partial `unpersist` of the dataframe to actively prune cached data as and when it turns obsolete for my use case.

EX:

```
srcDF.persist()
srcDF.count()
val df1 = srcDF.filter(col("bucket_id") === lit(1))
val result = df1.join(otherDF, Seq("field1"))
```

Given this execution is it possible for me to do a partial `unpersist()` to exclude everything with "bucket_id" = `1`

Comment: Why not persist the df after the filter, instead of before?

Comment: `srcDF ` is the source dataframe that is divided into buckets so that it can be fit in memory for a `broadcast` join. And these `broadcast` joins happen in iterations one bucket at a time. To avoid reading `srcDF` from hdfs every time I persist it before the joins begin. Once I am done with say bucket #1 I want to unpersist data of bucket #1 before moving on to bucket #2 and so on.